# Bootstrap alert message is not working inside angular run blocks under ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am doing sample application to autologut if user is idle for 30 Min. before 1 minutes to logOut have to show an warning message to the user.

So i have calculated the minutes and show the warning messages in Bootstrap.
But alert message is Not showing properly inside run.
Javascript alert is working fine but Bootstrap alert is not working.

```
    app.run(function ($rootScope, $cacheFactory, $interval, $timeout) {


    alert('1 more sec');

    function load() {

        alert('you have 1 more sec to autoLogOut');
        $rootScope.showError = true;
        $rootScope.error = "helloo";
        $rootScope.errorMessage = 'you have 1 more sec to autoLogOut';
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.doFade = true;
        }, 2500);
    }





    // Execute every time a state change begins
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $rootScope) {


    load();

    });
});
```

Its working  inside run block.

Problem:
Not working under

In Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0 " data-semver="1.4.0 " src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.run(function ($rootScope, $cacheFactory, $interval, $timeout) {


    alert('1 more sec');

    function load() {

        alert('you have 1 more sec to autoLogOut');
        $rootScope.showError = true;
        $rootScope.error = "helloo";
        $rootScope.errorMessage = 'you have 1 more sec to autoLogOut';
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.doFade = true;
        }, 2500);
    }





    // Execute every time a state change begins
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $rootScope) {


    load();

    });
});

</script>
    </head>

<body>

  <div data-ng-show="showError" ng-class="{fade:doFade} " class="alert alert-danger ">
    <strong>Error:</strong>{{errorMesage}}
    <p> {{error}}</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Inside the $stateChangeStart , it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Tried implementing your code. one bracket u missed at the end of **run** method.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.run(function ($rootScope, $cacheFactory, $interval, $timeout) {
      alert('you have 1 more sec to autoLogOut');

        $rootScope.showError = true;
        $rootScope.error = "helloo";
        $rootScope.errorMessage = 'you have 1 more sec to autoLogOut';
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.doFade = true;
        }, 2500);

});
```

see the plunker below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jiTGGF60Lll8OpUXjHTs?p=preview

Comment: Same thing works for me, while copying i miss the code , My Question is Bootstrap alert message is not working inside angular run blocks? Bootstrap alert is not working there. i have  updated your link https://plnkr.co/edit/55oBcDHAgjz7X72CYFFz?p=preview